# Error: PRECISION expected input to be a number but got the list [-4] instead in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to put precision to 4 decimal places in a result that is stored in the patch. But then try to get this error: PRECISION expected input to be a number but got the list [-4] instead. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
turtles-own [ e x y my-home ]
patches-own [ my-agent, en ]

to test
ask turtles
  [
    set e (x - y)
    ask my-home
    [
      set en [ e ] of my-agent
      set en precision en 2
    ]
 
   die 
  ]
end
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, but one thing, that seems odd, is that you use e. When you type that into netlogo, you will see, that `e` is highligted in orange, since it is a mathematical constant. You probably have to change that name

Answer (score 1):

I also cannot reproduce the error, but this works:

```
turtles-own [ e_ ]
to setup 
  ca
  crt 1
  ask turtles
  [
    set e_ 0.123456789
  ]

end

to go
  ask turtles [
    set e_ (precision e_ 2)
  ]
end

;; now put the standard two buttons on the canvas

;; click "inspect turtle",
;; or type `e_` at the `turtle>` prompt of the command console.
```

So as user Lena said in her comment, a property `e` *cannot* be used, because of the name conflict with the  `e` constant for Natural Logs. The "Check" feature of the Code tab *will* complain about `e` but not `e_` (or `f`, or `e1`...).

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `my-agent` has been set to an agentset instead of a single agent. In that case, `of` produces a list instead of a number.

Comment: Steve Railsback. Exactly. So, in that context, I can't use "precision" right?